# jQuery index of item in selector

Tags: jquery

this is pseudo code

```
  var index_of_myid = $('.selection').indexOf($('#myid));
```

not sure if this is right is this possible if you can understand what I'm trying to do

**EDIT**

```
 <div>
    <div class="selector"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="selector"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="selector" id="myid"></div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="selector" id="myid2"></div>
 </div>
```

I just need to know what number selector is the myid

Comment: I hope this title is good description so others find it useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely you mean to be using jQuery's [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) as opposed to the [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp) JS string method:

```
var index_of_myid = $('.selection').index($('#myid'));
```

See http://api.jquery.com/index/