# jQuery: How can I detect the position of a specific item in the list?

Tags: jquery

How can I detect the position of a specific item in the list ?

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li class="current">
  <li>
</ul>
```

I need to know in which position the current item is. In this case the result should be 3.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery index of item in selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498600/jquery-index-of-item-in-selector)

Comment: This is not a duplicate! @Patrick wants to know the index within a parent element, not the index within a jQuery selector.

Comment: Agreed this is not a duplicate, it's a different question with a different ideal solution.

Comment: It's the same thing. All that changes is his selector: `ul > li`.

Comment: @meagar - It's not.  Look at the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("ul li.current").index() + 1;
```

Noe that this is *not* the accepted answer in the other question, the situation is different when dealing with siblings.  [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) (without arguments) gives the sibling-index, which is all you need here.

*Edit:* just re-read the question, this is 0-based so it'd result in `2` not `3`, just add 1 to the `.index()` result if you're after 1-based numbering.

Comment: will this work? I was under the impression you'd have to do: $("ul li").index(".current");??

Comment: @Thomas - A few new overloads were added in jQuery 1.4, with no arguments you can just get the index amongst your siblings :)

Comment: it always returns "-1" ... I'm sure the selector is correct: $("ul li.pager-current").index(); what am I doing wrong ? I'm sure it exists. I.e. length gives 1 (it is detected)

Comment: It worked by doing this: $(".pager").index($(".pager-current"));

Answer (score 0):

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

> > If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the 
> >     position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.